# Font Issue with CSS/Javascript Slider. Font Not Displaying on Remote Server but Works in Local Server

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

It looks like the font is not working with my carousel (or slider). I do not have the font it uses installed on my computer. On my local, testing server the left and right arrows and the buttons work fine. On the remote server they do not. Remotely, it may even be using another font. That dagger or cross shaped character is not in the "slick" font. I put this in the head of the template (Dreamweaver) page and in my custom CSS file in case there was some problem with it being used solely in the slick-theme.css file: @font-face { font-family: slick; src: url('fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg'); }. The carousel comes with its own CSS file/s... slick.css and slick-theme.css. I also placed copies of the fonts into the main font folder. The originals are in slick/fonts/.

This page will show screenshots of the slider on my local server and on the remote server. http://sungraffix.net/img/misc/slider-issue.html

This is in the template page so it will also be in every page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face { font-family: slick; src: url('../fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg'); }  

    .header-div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url (../img/t-shirts-header-wide-1920x180.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 75%;
        margin: 50px auto;
    }

    .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
        color: black;
        /* font-size: 18pt; */
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
(Page Content with the Scripts Below It.)

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
      $(".center").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
      $(".variable").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        variableWidth: true
      });
    });
  </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

This is the slick-theme.css file:

```
@charset 'UTF-8';
/* Slider */
.slick-loading .slick-list
{
    background: #fff url('ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

/* Icons */
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url('fonts/slick.eot');
    src: url('fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg');
}
/* Arrows */
.slick-prev,
.slick-next
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);

    cursor: pointer;

    color: #4d004d;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus
{
    color: #4d004d;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-prev:hover:before,
.slick-prev:focus:before,
.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
.slick-next.slick-disabled:before
{
    opacity: .25;
}



.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 1;

    opacity: .75;
    color: #4d004d;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-prev
{
    left: -50px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev
{
    right: -40px;
    left: auto;
}
.slick-prev:before
{
    content: '←';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before
{
    content: '→';
}

.slick-next
{
    right: -30px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next
{
    right: auto;
    left: -25px;
}
.slick-next:before
{
    content: '→';
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-next:before
{
    content: '←';
}

/* Dots */
.slick-dotted.slick-slider
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-dots
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;

    display: block;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    list-style: none;

    text-align: center;
}
.slick-dots li
{
    position: relative;

    display: inline-block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-dots li button
{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;

    cursor: pointer;

    color: #4d004d;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover,
.slick-dots li button:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-dots li button:hover:before,
.slick-dots li button:focus:before
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.slick-dots li button:before
{
    font-family: 'slick';
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    content: '•';
    text-align: center;

    opacity: .25;
    color: #4d004d;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before
{
    opacity: .75;
    color: #4d004d;
}
```

This is the slick.css file.

```
/* Slider */
.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;

    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;

    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;

    height: auto;

    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

In case I was unable to place the images here, this page will show screenshots of the slider on my local server and on the remote server. http://sungraffix.net/img/misc/slider-issue.html If someone wants to look at any of the associated files that come with this slider I will be happy to copy them to Google Drive and provide a link. This is where I got the files for the slider: http://www.jqueryrain.com/2014/04/slick-jquery-fully-responsive-carousel-plugin/ It would be nice to be able to use such templates instead of building from scratch... which would require much more time.

It would be really great if someone happens to know what this problem is.  Perhaps someone has used templates like these before.

Comment: Everything that is on my local server has definitely been uploaded to the remote one... so there is nothing missing remotely.

Answer (score 1):

They can't be in the main font folder, if your css file is `/css/slick/slick.css` then the slick fonts have to go in `/css/slick/fonts/` because the CSS file is trying to load from its relative location.

```
 src: url('fonts/slick.eot');
```

Means the current directory of the CSS file inside a subdirectory called fonts.

Comment: The fonts are in the slick/fonts/ folder. I just placed a copy of them in the main fonts folder and added the css for them to my custom css file and head of the pages just to make sure there would be no problem with them being used.

Comment: And the permissions on the slick/fonts directory and files are correct on your remote? That's gotten me a couple of times.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "permissions."

Comment: I went into FileZilla and right-clicked on the folders and got a little panel for permissions. Never knew about or considered doing that. I put check marks in all the boxes for the folders and files. Didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already solved it , but if not, i found a solution.

I just solved it .

As I mentionned previously I cant put UTF-8 in all my site so I found that in the file slick-theme.css row 92 was defined

```
      `.slick-prev:before
         {
           content: 'â†';
            }
           [dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before
            {
            content: 'â†’';
            }
              `
```

which is the same that i saw in my web

so in another file of the library I found
                    `$slick-prev-character: "\2190" !default;`

so I just tryed to bring the numer of the character to the css definition

```
          `.slick-prev:before
              {
             content: '\2190';
             }
            [dir='rtl'] .slick-prev:before
             {
              content: '\2190';
              }`
```

Which in some way solve the UTF-8 problem which was to convert

```
                `content: 'â†';`
```

on

```
                `content: '\2190';`
```

Hope helps others . 
Regards 
Sergio